# Java EventListener inside of SwingWorker

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, serial-port, swingworker

OK, so I'm a bit new to `SwingWorker` in Java.

I've built a Java GUI that, when the "Start" button is pressed, launches several `SwingWorker` threads. The first thread simply keeps track of run time and updates the GUI appropriately. The second one plays a series of sounds files. The third (and problematic) thread should monitor the serial port for incoming data to be manipulated later on down the road. All of these threads will be running for a while, hence them being `SwingWorkers`.

I am using the jSSC library (https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/wiki/jSSC_examples) to read data from the serial port, and it does so by firing an eventListener.

**My question:** Is it redundant/inelegant to code an EventListener inside of a `SwingWorker` thread? And if so, is there a better way to go about this?

Here is a bit of my code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    SerialPort serialPort = findPort(); // returns a serialport I can use to read data from.

    SwingWorker worker1 = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            long elapsedTime, startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (true){
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                elapsedTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000;
                jTimeField.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", elapsedTime/3600, (elapsedTime%3600)/60, elapsedTime%60));
                if (isCancelled()){} /* Check if thread has been canceled */
            }
        }
    };

    SwingWorker worker2 = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            // This Thread: Plays music files; Self terminates; On termination also terminates worker 1 and 3 via cancel().
        }
    };

    SwingWorker worker3 = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialPortReader());
            return null;
        }
        class SerialPortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

            @Override
            public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
                byte buffer[];
                if (event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0){
                    buffer = serialPort.readBytes();
                    for (byte b: buffer){
                        // Do stuff with incoming data
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Any and all constructive criticism is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It does not do any good to add the event listener in your swingworker thread and then return once that's done. Why not just add the listener from your EDT and, if it takes long to process events, fire off processing threads from there? Listening to events can't be blocking, that would defeat the entire Observer pattern.